# Accessing child class data from parent class with PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop

I want to add some data form child class to parent class using the same method and also want to retrieve the data. Please check the example code that will help you for better understanding.

```
class HTML{

    public function add_control(){

    }

    public function all_controls(){

    }

}

class Control1 extends HTML
{

    public function register_controls()
    {

        $this->add_control([
            'name' => 'a',
            'label' => 'A',
        ]);

        $this->add_control([
            'name' => 'b',
            'lable' => 'B',
        ]);
    }

}

class Control2 extends HTML{

    public function register_controls()
    {

        $this->add_control([
            'name' => 'c',
            'label' => 'C',
        ]);


    }
}

(new HTML)->all_controls();
```

**Sample Output** ['a','b','c']
I hope you got my point.

Comment: You have said what you want, but there doesn't seem to be any attempt to solve your own problem.

Comment: That's not really how inheritance works. If you have an individual instance of your `HTML` class, which is what it looks like you want, it doesn't have any knowledge of `Control1` or `Control2` instances (or even that those subclasses exist). You might want to look at something like the [Composite Pattern](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Structural/Composite/README.html)

Comment: @NigelRen , I actually don't know how to solve this problem the reason why I asked.

Comment: Thank you @iainn , let me check if that can solve my problem

Comment: You can try using [abstract classes and methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

Comment: Not in that way possible, because `(new HTML)->all_controls();` is a new instance having no idea about the other instances. This is why you use OOP to have encapsulation. You could HTML make a static class with a static "Controller Collection". Then you could do `HTML::all_controls()`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your data is in a class variable. I didn't quite understand your point. It is not really possible to get the data of the child... It would be possible with a static class variable but then you won't be able to use `$this` in the `add_control($data)` function. All data will then be stored in one variable which is shared by all the three classes. This is my approach to your problem, I hope it solves your question.

```
<?php

class HTML{
    protected static $data;

    public function add_control($data) {
        self::$data[] = $data;
    }

    public function all_controls() {
        var_dump(self::$data);
    }

}

class Control1 extends HTML
{

    public function register_controls() {

        $this->add_control([
            'name' => 'a',
            'label' => 'A',
        ]);

        $this->add_control([
            'name' => 'b',
            'lable' => 'B',
        ]);
    }

}

class Control2 extends HTML{

    public function register_controls() {
        $this->add_control([
            'name' => 'c',
            'label' => 'C',
        ]);
    }
}
$html = new HTML();
$control1 = new Control1();
$control2 = new Control2();
$control1->register_controls();
$control2->register_controls();
$html->all_controls();
?>
```

**Edit:**
After the hint of Markus Zeller... you can also make the `all_controls()` function static. Then there will be no need to create an object of the class HTML. If this will suit your problem.

```
class HTML {

public static function all_controls() {
      var_dump(self::$data); //or any other echo method
}

}
//other stuff...
$control1->register_controls();
$control2->register_controls();
HTML::all_controls(); //no object of HTML necessary
```

Comment: Thanks for writing out my comment as an answer. Hint: You can make `all_controls()` static as well, then no $html instance is required at all.

Comment: yes, you're right. I thought I'd leave it at the static variable, since he apparently wanted an instance of the HTML class (see last line of his code)...  I will update the code a little.

Comment: Another improvement suggestion: Instead of `array_push(HTML::$data, $data);` use `self::$data[] = $data;`. 1) Having classname itself is not good when renaming the class, 2) Adding to an array using `[]` syntax is more efficient.